# Meaning of bitcoincharts.com REST API return json data keys

Tags: json, bitcoin

I am trying to show bitcoin price details on my website. So I choose the data source for that as http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/markets.json
But I can not understand the keys of json objects meaning.
May I know the meaning of the keys in returning json objects. Keys are as follows.
volume, bid, high, currency, currency_volume,ask,close,avg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are standard market terms

**Volume** is the number of bitcoins traded in the last 24h

**Bid** is the current lowest price that someone is willing to sell at

**High** is the highest price that was traded at in the last 24h

**Currency** is the money that is being used to compare the price aganist (I.e., EUR or USD)

**Currency** volume is the amount of currency traded in the last 24h

**Ask** is the current highest price that a buyer is will to buy at

**Close**, Not sure what is in this context, I assume it would be the price of bitcoins at the very start of the 24h period

**Avg** is the average trade price in the currency in the last 24 hours

None of these actually tell you the last trade price, which is technically the current price of bitcoins, the Api does provide this as **last_trade**. There is also a **low** which tells you the lowest price in the last 24h

Comment: In this returning json object, bid price of USD is showing as 43104290430.000000000000. It is very large. In reality it is now 433.81 by  google result.

Comment: Agreed, the first USD price does look a little odd. The API does include USD prices for bitcoins from other exchanges, I'd suggest using another exchange that you know to provide high volume prices, or look at taking an average bid/ask price from all USD markets listed